# How to get the default value for RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

I want to know what is the default value for EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS extra for RecognizerIntent.

In the documentation descibed constant android.speech.extras.SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, but it cannot be found.